# Randomly pick item from list with variable probabilities

Tags: c#, performance

This is supposed to randomly pick out the pieces for a Tetris clone. When a piece doesn't get drawn, its probability of getting drawn increases. I want to know if there is a way to do any part of this (or the whole idea) more efficiently. I'm also curious how you would judge the readability. Thank you.

This is the class that returns a random item via `DrawItem()`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class WeightedRNG<T>
{
    private List<RNGItem<T>> _RNGItems;
    private Random _RNG;

    public WeightedRNG(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        PopulateList(items);
        _RNG = new Random();
    }

    private void PopulateList(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        _RNGItems = new List<RNGItem<T>>();
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            _RNGItems.Add(new RNGItem<T>(1, item));
        }
    }
    private IEnumerable<int> CompileItemsForDrawing()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _RNGItems.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < _RNGItems[i].Weight; k++)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }
    private int GetWeightSum()
    {
        return _RNGItems.Sum(n => n.Weight);
    }

    public T DrawItem()
    {
        int index = CompileItemsForDrawing().ToArray()[_RNG.Next(GetWeightSum())];

        foreach (RNGItem<T> item in _RNGItems)
        {
            item.AddWeight();
        }
        _RNGItems[index].ResetWeight();

        return _RNGItems[index].Item;
    }

    public string[] GetAllOdds()
    {
        //this method only exists in order to have debug output in the right format for the form
        List<RNGItem<T>> temp = new List<RNGItem<T>>(_RNGItems);
        temp.Sort();
        int range = GetWeightSum();
        string[] ss = new string[temp.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        {
            ss[i] = temp[i].Item + " " + (((double)temp[i].Weight / range) * 100).ToString("N3");
        }
        return ss;
    }
}
```

And the `RNGItem` class that comprises the list in `WeightedRNG`

```
using System;
public class RNGItem<T> : IComparable<RNGItem<T>>
{
    public int Weight { get; private set; }
    public T Item { get; private set; }

    public RNGItem(int weight, T item)
    {
        Weight = weight;
        Item = item;
    }

    public void AddWeight()
    {
        Weight++;
    }

    public void ResetWeight()
    {
        Weight = 1;
    }

    public int CompareTo(RNGItem<T> other)
    {
        //gets sorted in descending order
        return Weight.CompareTo(other.Weight) * -1;
    }
}
```

I used it like this for testing, a simple form with a Button and a TextBox for output:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class TetrisForm : Form
{
    public WeightedRNG<string> WeightedRNG;

    public TetrisForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WeightedRNG = new WeightedRNG<string>(new string[]{ "Type_A", "Type_B", "Type_C", "Type_D", "Type_E", "Type_F", "Type_G"});
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = WeightedRNG.DrawItem();

        foreach (var t in WeightedRNG.GetAllOdds())
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(t + "\n");
        }
        richTextBox1.AppendText("##########\n");
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();           
    }
}
```

Comment: We can give better reviews when you post the whole class including the using statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you have to normalize weighted probability so that they will sum up to 1.
Then pick a number betwen [0-1) and then check where the probability selected fall and pick the corresponding element :

```
        // event probability land here
        //               |
        //               V
        // |__S__|__L__|__T__|__I__| (size of weighted probability will change after eachn normalization, they born equals but some block became bigger, other smaller)
        //
        // after selection change  weight of not selected (increase with your policy) and re-normalize values
```

That said i have the feeling that this is a triky way to express a simple random disrtibution, so you can basically get rid of all the weighting process and use the plain random result.

So even if i am not persuaded that your goal is "valid" i have written a simple program to show you what i mean with the weighting process (that IMHO can be usefull as patter in other scenarioes). I have used a brand new conde, because as stated in the comment is not clear how to use yours.
That said code proposed is really short and more like a "pseudo code" intended to portrait a clear picture about what i said before.

```
    class Program
    {
        private class TetrisPieces
        {
            public double NormalizedWeight = 0d;
            public double Weight = 1;
            public string Name = "";
        }

        private static Random _rng = new Random(0);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<TetrisPieces> tetrisPieces = new List<TetrisPieces>();
            tetrisPieces.Add(new TetrisPieces() { Name = "SquaredBlock" });
            tetrisPieces.Add(new TetrisPieces() { Name = "LBlock" });
            tetrisPieces.Add(new TetrisPieces() { Name = "TBlock" });
            tetrisPieces.Add(new TetrisPieces() { Name = "IBlock" });

            Program.NormalizeWeights(tetrisPieces); //complete the initialization with first normalization of weight

            Console.WriteLine("Selection 1 : " + Program.RandomChoose(tetrisPieces).Name + " (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)");
            Console.WriteLine("Selection 2 : " + Program.RandomChoose(tetrisPieces).Name + " (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)");
            Console.WriteLine("Selection 3 : " + Program.RandomChoose(tetrisPieces).Name + " (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)");
            Console.WriteLine("Selection 4 : " + Program.RandomChoose(tetrisPieces).Name + " (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)");
            Console.WriteLine("Selection 5 : " + Program.RandomChoose(tetrisPieces).Name + " (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)");
            Console.WriteLine("Selection 6 : " + Program.RandomChoose(tetrisPieces).Name + " (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)");
            Console.WriteLine("Selection 7 : " + Program.RandomChoose(tetrisPieces).Name + " (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)");
            Console.WriteLine("Selection 8 : " + Program.RandomChoose(tetrisPieces).Name + " (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void NormalizeWeights(List<TetrisPieces> items)
        {
            double totalWeight = items.Select(item => item.Weight).Sum();

            double lowerProbability = 0d;
            Console.WriteLine("Normalization Debug");
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                item.NormalizedWeight = item.Weight / totalWeight;
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} [{lowerProbability}-{lowerProbability + item.NormalizedWeight})");

                lowerProbability += item.NormalizedWeight;
            }
        }

        private static TetrisPieces RandomChoose(List<TetrisPieces> items)
        {
            double eventProbability = _rng.NextDouble();
            Console.WriteLine("Extraction Debug : pEvent = " + eventProbability);

            double lowerProbability = 0d;
            TetrisPieces candidate = null;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (lowerProbability <= eventProbability && eventProbability < (lowerProbability + item.NormalizedWeight))
                {
                    candidate = item;
                    break;
                }
                lowerProbability += item.NormalizedWeight;
            }

            if (candidate == null)
            {
                //you should never land here, but maybe rounding error may be unexpected, anyway if you are here you meant to choose the last peace
                Console.WriteLine("Item not choosed");
                candidate = items.Last();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Extraction Debug : Item selected -> " + candidate.Name);

            var nonSelectedItems = items.Where(item => item != candidate);
            foreach (var item in nonSelectedItems)
                item.Weight++;

            Program.NormalizeWeights(items);
            return candidate;

            // event probability land here
            //               |
            //               V
            // |__S__|__L__|__T__|__I__| (size of weighted probability will change after eachn normalization, they born equals but some block became bigger, other smaller)
            //
            // after selection change  weight of not selected (increase with your policy) and re-normalize values
        }
    }
```

Here the output :

```
Normalization Debug
SquaredBlock [0-0,25)
LBlock [0,25-0,5)
TBlock [0,5-0,75)
IBlock [0,75-1)
Extraction Debug : pEvent = 0,72624326996796
Extraction Debug : Item selected -> TBlock
Normalization Debug
SquaredBlock [0-0,285714285714286)
LBlock [0,285714285714286-0,571428571428571)
TBlock [0,571428571428571-0,714285714285714)
IBlock [0,714285714285714-1)
Selection 1 : TBlock (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)
Extraction Debug : pEvent = 0,817325359590969
Extraction Debug : Item selected -> IBlock
Normalization Debug
SquaredBlock [0-0,3)
LBlock [0,3-0,6)
TBlock [0,6-0,8)
IBlock [0,8-1)
Selection 2 : IBlock (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)
Extraction Debug : pEvent = 0,768022689394663
Extraction Debug : Item selected -> TBlock
Normalization Debug
SquaredBlock [0-0,307692307692308)
LBlock [0,307692307692308-0,615384615384615)
TBlock [0,615384615384615-0,769230769230769)
IBlock [0,769230769230769-1)
Selection 3 : TBlock (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)
Extraction Debug : pEvent = 0,558161191436537
Extraction Debug : Item selected -> LBlock
Normalization Debug
SquaredBlock [0-0,3125)
LBlock [0,3125-0,5625)
TBlock [0,5625-0,75)
IBlock [0,75-1)
Selection 4 : LBlock (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)
Extraction Debug : pEvent = 0,206033154021033
Extraction Debug : Item selected -> SquaredBlock
Normalization Debug
SquaredBlock [0-0,263157894736842)
LBlock [0,263157894736842-0,526315789473684)
TBlock [0,526315789473684-0,736842105263158)
IBlock [0,736842105263158-1)
Selection 5 : SquaredBlock (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)
Extraction Debug : pEvent = 0,558884794618415
Extraction Debug : Item selected -> TBlock
Normalization Debug
SquaredBlock [0-0,272727272727273)
LBlock [0,272727272727273-0,545454545454545)
TBlock [0,545454545454545-0,727272727272727)
IBlock [0,727272727272727-1)
Selection 6 : TBlock (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)
Extraction Debug : pEvent = 0,906027066011926
Extraction Debug : Item selected -> IBlock
Normalization Debug
SquaredBlock [0-0,28)
LBlock [0,28-0,56)
TBlock [0,56-0,76)
IBlock [0,76-1)
Selection 7 : IBlock (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)
Extraction Debug : pEvent = 0,442177873310716
Extraction Debug : Item selected -> LBlock
Normalization Debug
SquaredBlock [0-0,285714285714286)
LBlock [0,285714285714286-0,535714285714286)
TBlock [0,535714285714286-0,75)
IBlock [0,75-1)
Selection 8 : LBlock (the same value already printed by extraction debug, it's not anoter extraction)
```

-- EDIT : added detail about my gut feeling on necessity of balancement on evenly distributed number generator.

As stated in the comment i think that a plain selection (like the first one) is all you need. I think that the balancement proposed does not change probabiliry in a signifcant way.

Here my "gut feeling proof" :
if there is no balancement at all the, probability for pieces in a row are :

1. 25%
2. 6%
3. 1%
4. 0.3% (negletable)

With the current balancement :

1. 25%
2. 3%
3. 0.3% (negletable)

So as you can see they drop a bit faster, but this is a thing only in a very unlikely scenario.

So if it's really a no-no situation that a piece is picked three time in a row, just pick them randomly and update a block list (a counter that restart every time the pieces is different of the previous and increment when they are equal).
If it's really a no-no situation that a piece is picked fewer time (than three, aka two times) use a stringet block list that stop at two.

Because as you can see in the probability printed, with only few selection (the 9 seleciont i made) due to the randomness and evenly distribution of PNRG you actually does not use you algorithm (even after applying weight the probability fluctuate arround 25%).

To be more precise 97% of the time you algorithm is just equivalent to a simple picking, and as simple picking does not generate duplicate. If you accept single duplicate then equivalence grow to ~99%.
So basically what i am saing is that if thing changes only in 3% to <1% of scenarioes (depending on how stringent are your requirements). For that reason i think it's simpler to stick to plain randomness and then validate output against a block list (in case discard and generate again and again) if really is a no-no situation (or do nothing if it's acceptable).

IMHO balancements are meaningfull only if you have a non random surce, or a source with distribution different form the one you choose. But you need a raondm distribution, and you have a random distribution, so i think no balancements are needed.

And last but not the least, i personally think that all this methodology (block list or balancement) will negatively affect the chance, making games predictable. Let radomness do it's work :)

PS : https://tetris.fandom.com/wiki/Random_Generator
here some detail on  actual algorithm, as you can see it generate a random permutation of symbol list and the deal them.

```
tetrisPieces.OrderBy ( piece => _rng.NextDouble() );
```

Comment: I can see how this is better than my approach, thank you. What do you mean by 
'i am not persuaded that your goal is "valid"' ?

Comment: @Cooky sorry if a worded badly (english is not my language). What i mean is that in the first selection every piece has 1/4 probability to be selected. Then you re-balance probability to make it "more uniform". But if probability was uniform in the first place you have no need to rebalance (weight normalization) just do another selection again with probability as is. If you see, as the algorithm proceede the balancement is just a noise arround 1/4. So IMHO all the concern about change probability on the fly is just a non issue (i mean that with "valid")

Comment: It's also not my first language, thanks for clearing that up. The idea is that you won't draw even 1000 times during a regular Tetris round, so when you randomly get the same piece over and over again, it has significant impact on the game. This is just to prevent the same pieces occurring too often in a row, while still maintaining some chance for it to happen.

Comment: @Cooky that's what my gut feeling disagree upon. I have not digged into datails, so maybe something counter intuitive happen here. But if PRNG of C# is evenly distributed it's very unlikely that you keep the same piece over and over. If you does not balance probability, the likelyhood to get the same piece four time in a row is 0.3% (low). Now i update the answer to make it clear (here in comment is difficult)